# m2eclipse resolves workspace artifacts and tld files

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, taglib

We have a multi-module maven project. One of the sub modules is a tag library. We us eclipse with m2eclipse (Spring Tool Suite 3.1).

When I start mvn jetty:run inside eclipse **without** "Resolve workspace artifacts" everything runs fine. Our taglib jar is picked up from local maven repository. Fine.

When I start mvn jetty:run inside eclipse **with** "Resolve workspace artifacts" our tags are not picked up. Instead of running the tag handler, the tag is printed into the html as is.

I guess that tld scanning of the servlet container (jetty) does not work with m2eclipses feature "Resolve workspace artifacts".

Of course we could move our tag library to a standalone project. Then we could still enjoy the benefits of "workspace artifact resolving" for all the other sub modules.

Does anybody has a better solutions with keeping out tag library as a sub module?